# A few questions about Riemann's Main Formula in the paper On the Number of Primes Less Than a Given Magnitude

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Sorry for asking multiple questions these days about the same topic, but the thing is I was doing a school project about Riemann's zeta function so I kind of suffered when reading Riemann's paper On the Number of Primes Less Than a Given Magnitude. The first half flows pretty well to me but I kind of got stuck after this integral was derived through Fourier Transform:

\begin{align}
f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty} \frac{\log\zeta(s)}{s}x^s ds
\end{align}

Since directly plugging in the expression of $\log\zeta(s)$ would cause the integral to diverge, integration by parts is used here:

\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{2\pi i\log x}\int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty} \left( \frac{d}{ds}\frac{\log\zeta(s)}{s}\right)x^s ds
\end{align}

Everything makes sense right now, but after this, Riemann proposed an identity without giving any proof, and I do not think this is a trivial result (Question 1):

\begin{align}
-\log\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}+1\right)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m \log\left(1+\frac{s}{2n}\right)-\frac{s}{2}\log m
\end{align}

And then all the terms of the integral have been unified into the form of $\frac{d}{ds}\frac{1}{s}\log\left(1-\frac{s}{\beta}\right)$ after this, which makes sense if we accept the identity, except for the constant term $\log\frac{1}{2}$.

After that, the paper just goes from seemingly nonsense to calculate $\frac{d}{d\beta}\frac{1}{s}\log\left(1-\frac{s}{\beta}\right)=\frac{1}{\beta(\beta-s)}$, I do not see why here (Question 2)

Later on this integral is calculated:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{a+i\infty}^{a-i\infty} \frac{x^s}{\beta(\beta-s)} ds = \frac{x^\beta}{\beta} = \int_0^x t^{\beta-1} dt
\end{align}

which I can see how it comes to appear in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4207291/evaluating-frac12-pi-i-intai-infty-a-i-infty-fracxss-betads-u)

And finally, the main formula of this paper, which is evident if we admit the results above:
\begin{align}
f(x)=Li(x)-\sum_{\rho} Li(x^\rho) + \log\frac{1}{2} + \int_x^\infty \frac{dt}{t(t^2-1)\log t}
\end{align}

So my questions are:

1. How is the expression of the Gamma function deduced
2. Why is $\frac{d}{d\beta}\frac{1}{s}\log\left(1-\frac{s}{\beta}\right)=\frac{1}{\beta(s-\beta)}$ calculated instead of $\frac{d}{ds}\frac{1}{s}\log\left(1-\frac{s}{\beta}\right)=-\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{s}{\beta}\right)}{s^2}-\frac{1}{s(\beta-s)}$

During my research process, I also found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02301.pdf), which gave me a lot of explanation towards some steps skipped by Riemann, but it still did not give any explanation for this process

Answer (score 2):

1. Look for the [product formula of the Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Weierstrass%27s_definition), deduced from the Weierstrass factorization theorem or Hadamard factorization theorem.
2. Riemann introduced auxiliary variable $\beta$ to calculate the integral(first differentiate by $\beta$ and integrating again).

Comment: I do not see the process of integrating by $d\beta$ in the paper, instead everything is regarding $ds$

Comment: Integrating $x^\beta/\beta$ with respect to $\beta$ gives ${\rm Li}(x^\beta)$.

Comment: I might have misread it but I think $Li(x^\beta)$ comes from the fact that $\frac{x^\beta}{\beta}=\int_0^x t^{\beta-1} dt$ and moving in the $\frac{1}{\log x}$, otherwise the $\frac{1}{\log x}$ would be redundant